nginx reverse proxy with laravel api and react
I'm developing an application with Laravel as API and separately NextJS, apart from that I'm using docker and nginx. I created a nginx config and can access the UI but I can't access the API endpoints in Laravel.
My docker-compose
services:

  ###### FRONTEND SERVICES

  ## Node container for regular execution of the Federer project
  findra-node:
    build:
      context: ./docker/node
    container_name: findra-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./federer
        target: /var/www/finaldraw/federer
    working_dir: /var/www/finaldraw/federer
    command: ["npm", "run", "dev"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "finaldraw.local:3000"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - frontend

  ###### BACKEND SERVICES

  ## Nginx container
  findra-nginx:
    container_name: findra-nginx
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      findra-php:
        condition: service_healthy
      findra-node:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${NGINX_PORT}
        target: 80
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "finaldraw.local:80"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  # PHP container for regular execution (contains and runs the Laravel base
  findra-php:
    container_name: findra-php
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}  
    user: www-data:www-data
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nadal
        target: /var/www/finaldraw/nadal
    working_dir: /var/www/finaldraw/nadal
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "php-fpm-healthcheck"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - backend

Nginx config
upstream federer {
  server findra-node:3000;
}

upstream nadal {
  server findra-php:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.local;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {    
        proxy_pass http://federer/; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;           
    } 

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://nadal/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

and PHP dockerfile exposes port 9000 and node dockerfile exposes port 3000.
As I mentioned above I can access the UI (http://mysite.local/) but when I want to send a request to PHP (http://finaldraw.local/api/) I can't access it. I get:
<html>

<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.27.0</center>
</body>

</html>


What is the exact URL you're trying to call?  From what context?

http://finaldraw.local/ works but http://finaldraw.local/api/  Or http://finaldraw.local:9000/api/ doesn't @DavidMaze

Where are you trying to call this from; from a container or the end user's browser or somewhere else?  In the findra-php container, are you using an Apache (HTTP) or PHP-FPM (FastCGI) base?

in findra-php I'm using PHP-FPM and I want to call to the browser, because I open the application in the browser and there I have to get or post data to PHP @DavidMaze (I've created a room chat here)

PHP-FPM uses the FastCGI protocol and not HTTP.  Does it help to change proxy_pass to fastcgi_pass when forwarding to this backend?

so it's not necessary the upstream for the backend? @DavidMaze

You can keep the upstream blocks if you'd like.  (It might be clearer to make their names more closely match the target container names.)

My main idea is open mysite.local without port 3000 and see the UI (nextjs) in the browser and then request from the ui to backend but I can't @DavidMaze
